# Is there any way to estimate database size?

Tags: mysql

I currently intend on running my server on a 20GB server.
The server is mostly just having a LAMP stack, with ubuntu.

The data will mostly be held in a large table(about 50 columns)
The question is, given that about 1 GB is used for other server stuff, how much data can this table hold?

The table holds about 6 varchars with about 64 characters each. About 10 integer values and rest are binary values.
How much rows can this fit? Help is highly appreciated

Comment: Do you have any indexes?  They take up space too.  Sometimes more than the table.

Comment: Three indexes, all on varchars. (Also a primary int id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to get this done is use

```
  SHOW TABLE STATUS [{FROM | IN} db_name]
  [LIKE 'pattern' | WHERE expr]
```

You will get all the info about the table .

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I sound mean or stupid, but couldn't you install MySQL in your desktop or whatever other server, import/simulate your database content with all the indexes and so on in place, and actually see how much space it allocates, instead of just guessing? :)

Anyway, anything measured in that little numbers shouldn't be a problem for MySQL itself; it's another question if the SQL queries and your application itself are properly done.

Answer (score 0):

You could run this query:

```
SELECT table_schema "DB Name", Round(Sum(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) "DB Size in MB"
FROM information_schema.tables
GROUP BY table_schema;
```

Or you could go in */var/libs/mysql/* directory and check size of directories containing database files with the command *du -sh **